# javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: 535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted. Learn more at

Tags: java, spring, email

I'm trying to send mails using my java app and gmail. Here is my config:

```
  mail:
    host: smtp.gmail.com
    username: mail@gmail.com
    password: password
    port: 465
    protocol: smtps
```

But, unfortunately I'm getting following error:

```
javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: 535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted. Learn more at
535 5.7.8  https://support.google.com/mail/?p=BadCredentials l18-20020a056402345200b0043a5004e714sm3019845edc.64 - gsmtp

        at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport$Authenticator.authenticate(SMTPTransport.java:947)
        at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.authenticate(SMTPTransport.java:858)
```

I have enabled access to less secured apps on my gmail account and I'm sure that provided username and password are valid.

Can someone help me with this?

Thanks

Comment: The error seems pretty clear to me. What have you tried, where and why are you stuck? Are you sure that you've used your own mail address and password?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Google has announced that it’s disabling the Less Secure Apps feature on some Google accounts from May 30th, 2022.

To be able to send messages through your gmail account, you can set up an app password in your Google account.

An app password works like an alternate password for your account. It can only be used by the applications you share it with, so it’s more secure than sharing your primary password

If you’d like to use an app password,[you’ll need to turn on two factor authentication for your Google account](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/185839) . After that, you can create an app specific password for WP Mail SMTP in the security settings for your Google account.

To do so, select Other (Custom name) as the app on the App passwords screen.

[image]

Then type in WP Mail SMTP or another name that will help you identify this password in the space provided.

[image]

After that, you just need to click the Generate button to create your password.

[image]

**Note**: any time you change your main Google account password, it will deactivate your app passwords as well. If you change your password frequently, this may not be the best workaround.

After generating password, you put your generated password in password property of your property file:

```
 mail:
    host: smtp.gmail.com
    username: mail@gmail.com
    password: <GENERATED_PASSWORD>
    port: 465
    protocol: smtps
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. Maybe you know answer for this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72931681/outgoing-traffic-to-ports-25-and-465-are-blocked

Comment: @PeterShneider is there any way to  automate this process in java?